# Should a meta_key or other key-value table columns use a HASH or BTREE index?

Tags: index, mariadb, wordpress

I've noticed that my WordPress database has BTREE indexes everywhere.

By my understanding, BTREE indexes allow more efficient < > and BETWEEN queries, but are otherwise less efficient than a HASH query for = and != queries.

This makes sense for some columns that might be filtered numerically (dates obviously, and IDs potentially, – though in practice ID > x doesn't seem very likely in WordPress), but I can't see any benefit for columns like meta_key which stores the text key of a key-value pair, or indeed the post_id column of a post_metadata table, which will almost without exception be JOINed to the posts table.

Would a HASH index be more performant? If so, is there any reason that my database is using BTREE indexes for these columns, or is this just a default? If not, what am I lacking in my understanding of indexes?

Comment: take a look at this Stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306316/b-tree-vs-hash-table  and see the constraints on primary keys

Comment: @nbk thanks, that’s helpful in explaining the differences, but I lack enough understanding of DB performance to be sure I’m applying it correctly. Given hashes are O(1), and a key-value table is unlikely to be queried other than for equality, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: i  believe meta_key is **not** a **primary key**, so hashes are out of the question, that was my hint at the end. Hashes need a lot of space to map them, that was explained in the post. also it takes a overhead to calculate the hash. using hashes because of the constraints is rare, and the balanced binary trees are the best till now.  also `HASH is only supported by the MEMORY storage engine.` another constraint which disqualifies it

Comment: Thanks, that’s probably the answers I need.

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong question.  The indexes that WP provides on the meta tables are inefficient.  (And the general EAV pattern sucks.)

This explains how to significantly improve the indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Back to your question:  BTree is about as fast as Hash (were it to exist).  And Hash is not available for InnoDB.  (InnoDB is the only 'engine' you should use for WP.)

I believe that the developer of InnoDB saw that "one side *does* fit all" when he implemented *only* BTree.